# "Почему нет" vs "почему бы и нет"

Tags: грамматика, падежи

What's the difference between "почему нет?" and "почему бы и нет?"

Comment: I believe it is just a shorter version of "почему бы и нет". Probably influenced by English "why not".

Comment: "Почему нет" is more colloquial and shorten. But so this is just synonyms.  Kirienko, just the reduction does'nt mean anyone influence, the more the English, you can see a long-known here -  "Pourquoi Pas?" (FR.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While "почему нет" indeed can serve a shorter form completely equivalent to "почему бы и нет", there's actually a use case when those forms are not interchangeable. Imagine following two conversations:

> Анна: А пошли в кино?

> Борис: Нет

> Анна: Почему нет? У тебя какие-то другие планы на вечер?

And:

> Анна: А пойдём в кино?

> Борис: Почему [бы и] нет, а пошли!

As you can see, in this case "почему нет" serve for two completely different purposes. One is like "why no?", the other one is like "why not"?

Answer (score 2):

"Почему бы и нет" is a valid translation of "why not" expressing a supposed possibility or opportunity of some action. Бы  is a particle originated from the verb быть.(It can/could be). As for "почему нет", it is a colloquial variation, when used in the same meaning, a shorter one. But it can also be used in a different meaning, like a question asking for a reason, then the stress is on the first word почему.

Comment: The stress cannot fall on почему here, regardless of the meaning.